# how add a file in every dir and subdir

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i need to put file in every dir and sub dir

i use bash on mac with brew

i tried this

```bash
for dir in \`//Users/oscarristolfi/Downloads/roma/\* . -type d\` ; do cp index.html   ; done
```

i' have tried but it show only echo, result

```bash
/Users/oscarristolfi/Downloads/roma/copia.sh: line 7: //Users/oscarristolfi/Downloads/roma/cerco-amici: is a directory
```

i try tu add a dir variable but nothing

```bash
for dir in \`//Users/oscarristolfi/Downloads/roma/\* . -type d\` ; do cp index.html  $dir/index.html ; done
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Did you generate this gibberish with AI? It starts with a `for` statement in the shell, and then a weirdly quoted piece of `find` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `find` instead of `for`.
Given that `index.html` exists in the current directory where you run `find` from:

```bash
find //Users/oscarristolfi/Downloads/roma/* -type d -exec cp index.html {} \;
```

Add options to `cp`:

- `-f` if you want to force overwriting an existing `index.html` in the target directory.
- `-n` if you don't want to overwrite an existing `index.html` in the target directory.

<sup>I'm not familiar with MacOS and the `//Users` part of the path, but I'm assuming it's some sort of link to the top of where the home directories are placed.</sup>